# Add new columns with specific ng-model to HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I am trying to add additional columns to a table inside a form. Adding the columns themselves is not that difficult but I don't know how to go about setting their ng-models.

This is my current code:
(HTML)

```
<button ng-click="add()" type="button">+ column</button>
        <table>
            <thead id="inputtablehead">
                <th class="theadlabel">(in 1.000 EUR)</th>
                <th>{{startyear}}</th>
                <th class="NBBCodesHeader">NBB Codes</th>
                <th>Source</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="input">
                <tr>
                    <td>number of months</td>
                    <td>
                        <input ng-model="input{{startyear}}.NumberMonths" type="text" class="{{startyear}}" required>
                    </td>
                        <td class="NBBCodes"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fixed assets</td>
                    <td>
                        <input ng-model="input{{startyear}}.FixedAssets" class="{{startyear}}" type="text" required>
                    </td>
                    <td class="NBBCodes">20/28</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Inventory</td>
                    <td>
                        <input ng-model="input{{startyear}}.Inventory" class="{{startyear}}" type="text" required>
                    </td>
                    <td class="NBBCodes">3</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

(JS)

```
angular.module("inputFields", []).controller("MyTable", function ($scope) { 
    $scope.startyear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var nextyear = new Date().getFullYear() - 1;
    $scope.add = function () {
        $(".NBBCodesHeader").before("<th>"+nextyear+"</th>");
        $(".input .NBBCodes").before('<td><input class='+nextyear+' type="text" required></td>');
        nextyear--;
    };
    });
```

So in my JS the `<input class='+nextyear+' type="text" required>` should become something like `<input ng-model="input'+nextyear+'.NumberMonths" class='+nextyear+' type="text" required>` for the `<td>` element added next to the 'number of months' row.

I was thinking to give ea row an id in the form of NumberMonths and then look up the id when adding the column.

So my question would be: is this a valid way to do it and how would I get this id? Or am I overthinking it and is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use standard javascript `[]` object notation for variable property names.

```
<input ng-model="input[startyear].Inventory"
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do DOM manipulations from a controller. It's not a good practice when working with AngularJS. A good rule to remember that is: don't use jQuery. It's a common mistake when starting working with AngularJS. And, in case you would be completely sure that you need to modify the DOM, do it always from a directive.

About your problem, maybe you can base your solution in create a data structure in your controller (a Javascript Object), and render it through a `ng-repeat` in your template. This way, if you modify the object (adding a new column), the template will be automatically updated.